# How do I use the SplClassLoader

Tags: php, psr-0

I am trying to understand and use the PSR-0 Autoloader. But it doesn't work.

My Folder structure:

Core/

- Library/
- Model/

My index.php in Root

```
<?php
require_once 'Core/Library/SplClassLoader.php';

$loader = new SplClassLoader('Core', 'Core');
$loader->register();



use Model\Post;
```

Post.php in Model folder.

```
<?php
namespace Model;

class Post implements PostInterface
{
// ...
```

PostInterface

```
<?php
namespace Model;

interface PostInterface
{
//...
```

I Get the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'Model\Post' not found in C:\wamp\www\Test\index.php on line 17

```
Line 17: Init new Post;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SplClassLoader works like this:

```
$loader = new SplClassLoader('NamespaceName', 'path/To/Base/Directory');
```

You are registering `Core` namespace here, but you don't have `Core\Model` namespace, but simply `Model`

Comment: You were correct, however, Now I finally got it to found the "Post model" but, I am having problem finding the PostInterface instead, 

 Fatal error: Interface 'PostInterface' not found in C:\wamp\www\Test\Core\Model\Post.php

<?php
namespace Model;

class Post implements PostInterface
{

Comment: And `PostInterface.php` is located in your `Core/Model` directory?

Comment: Yes, I simply missed out the Core\ part in PostInterface as well